# SQL Query only Select * From Column if All match another Column

Tags: sql

I have a list of invoice numbers that show multiple lines. I want to show a result of one invoice number if all lines are deleted. If any lines at all show not deleted, then remove it from the results.

| Invoice | Deleted |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 |  |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 |  |
| 3 | A |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | A |

| Result |  |
| --- | --- |
| Invoice | Deleted |
| 2 | A |
| 4 | A |

Another thought. What if I need to add another table that contains the customer name and narrow it down to one particular customer?

| Invoice | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Shop |
| 1 | Shop |
| 1 | Shop |

Comment: Please provide an explanation of the expected output. It's not clear from your question and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
select t.* from table_name t where invoice in (
select invoice
from table_name
group by invoice
having sum( case when Deleted<>'A' then 1 else 0 end)=0
)
```